# SSD health: Does free space on a LVM on LUKS volume also count as overprovisioning space?

Tags: encryption, luks, ssd, health

I've read multiple times that increasing the amount of overprovisioning space on a SSD is the same as leaving some space unused. (e.g. here: ["[...] storage that the operating system hasn’t allocated counts towards overprovisioning"](https://www.macworld.com/article/704243/how-much-storage-you-should-leave-unused-on-a-macs-ssd.html)

I have three questions regarding this:

1. Does this also apply to LVM on LUKS encrypted volumes? That is, can free space also be utilized as overprovisioning here?
2. If no, should I increase the factory-set amount of overprovisioning space in my SSD software to keep my SSD fast and healthy?
3. Does having overprovisioning space impose a security risk regarding my encryption setup?

PS: I have a Samsung 980 Pro NVMe which is used as a system drive.

Answer (score 1):

Over-provisioning means setting aside (extra) storage so that the SSD controller has little difficulty allocating new free blocks rapidly. ANY free space (in blocks) counts toward over-provisioning.

The simplest way to over-provision (in addition to the OEM over-provision) is to leave a section of the SSD outside of disk partitioning, unformatted and unwritten. This is likely unnecessary for typical end-user PC usage.   You might want this if you intend to fill the drive to near-capacity and demand highest I/O performance.

Be sure to TRIM the filesystem deletes; otherwise the SSD controller can't re-use the space. Most Linux systems have an fstrim service.  Alternatively mount a filesystem with the 'discard' option.

Comment: "ANY free space (in blocks) counts toward over-provisioning." => I was just wondering if the OS knows that there is some free space if it is encrypted. Since an empty LUKS partition that is in an encrypted state looks full according to gparted. That's why I wondered

Comment: The OS manages a filesystem (e.g. ntfs or ext4) and keeps a bitmap of the blocks of disk that are in-use (vs un-used).  So encryption causes no OS confusion. The SSD drive controller manages the FLASH storage of the drive and has no notion of an OS filesystem or it's content.  The SSD controller will only erase blocks that the the OS indicates (via the trim or discard command') are no longer needed as part of the OS file system. Neither OS nor SSD controller manages blocks based on data content.